# bundle.js is not updated on file edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

While using create-react-app, everything works fine for a while but suddenly bundle.js stop being updated when I edit the project's files and I need to close it and run `npm start` again.

I tried to to clean up the cache and close and reopen browser, but nothing of that works, so I'm guessing it's an issue with webpack.

Comment: It happened with two really simple starting projects so I don't think a code sample would tell much, but it might be because of safe-write like another poster said.

Answer (score 3):

Has it always been like that? Can you reproduce this problem with a fresh create-react-app project?

It could be related to "safe write" feature in some editors. Check the webpack docs regarding this: [Working with editors/IDEs supporting “safe write”](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#working-with-editors-ides-supporting-safe-write).

Comment: I started using PHPStorm just yesterday and I **do** have safe-write enabled so it's really likely that's the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Feel free to mark it as the solution for your problem if it worked for you :)